# Как запустить другой EXE от имени активного пользователя из EXE запущенного от имени админа?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Как из EXE, который запущен от имени администратора, запустить другой EXE от имени пользователя который на текущий момент залогинен в системе? `ShellExecute` не подходит, он передает второму EXE свои же права. Ищу пример кода с `CreateProcess` или другой функцией.

Comment: Есть пример на C++: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, для этого существует функция [CreateProcessAsUserW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw). [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668389/calling-createprocessasuser-from-c-sharp) есть пример кода на C#. Но требуется знать пароль другого пользователя.